# Change event on editable fields in html table only affecting top row calculated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have the following table with editable fields (columns).

[image: Table image]

Any change I make to the sellprice or casecost column fields, I would like the GP column field to update as the user types or changes values. My code is as follows.

```
function calculate() {

            $('tr #item_q_sellprice').change(function calculate() {
            //$('.productTable tr').on('change','#item_q_sellprice,#item_q_casecost',function calculate() {
            // $("input[type=text]").change(function () {                

                //fields used for calculations
                var newPrice = parseFloat($('tr #item_q_sellprice').val());                    
                var casecost = parseFloat($('tr #item_q_casecost').val());
                var casesize = parseFloat($('tr #item_q_casesize').val());
                var vatrate = parseFloat($('tr #item_productVat').val());

                //formulae
                var netprice = newPrice / (1 + vatrate / 100);
                var unitcost = casecost / casesize;
                var profit = (newPrice / (vatrate / 100 + 1)) - unitcost;

                var grossprofit = (profit / netprice) * 100

                //alert("change price: " + price);
                //Update GP field
                $('#item_grossProfit').val(grossprofit.toFixed(1));

            });

    }
```

My Html for the rows is as follows

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.q_description)
        </td>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.q_barcode)
        </td>
        <td>
            € @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.q_sellprice, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "calc-list" })
        </td>
        <td>
            € @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.q_casecost, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "calc-list" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.grossProfit, new { @class = "calc-list" })
        </td>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productDepartment)
        </td>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.productVat, "{0:0.0}",new { @class = "calc-list", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </td>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.q_stocklevel)
        </td>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id = item.q_guid }))'">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.q_casesize, new { @class = "calc-list", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </td>            

    </tr>
}
```

**Now this currently only works for the top row**, and not the rest of the table rows. I guess the error will be on my variable lines

```
var newPrice = parseFloat($('tr #item_q_sellprice').val());
```

How do I make it so any row where these fields (sellprice/casecost) are changed/updated also updates the corresponding GP column?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well..

Comment: Give your source text fields a common class, so you can select them in one go. Research jQuery's Tree Traversal methods like : parent, closest, next and prev https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: duplicate HTML IDs  are invalid. use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use of a `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html, and the reason your script fails. Using `$('tr #item_q_sellprice').val()` for example will only ever return the value of the first element with that `id`.

More importantly, your use of a `foreach` loop means that your view will never bind correctly. Instead, you need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail).

Give the elements your need in the calculations a class name, and then use relative selectors to find the associated elements in the same container (your `<tr>`).

The view should be (using a `for` loop)

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        ....
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].q_sellprice, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "sell-price calc-list" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].q_casecost, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "case-cost calc-list" })
        ....
    </tr>
}
```

Then your script becomes

```
$('.sell-price, .case-cost').change(function calculate() {
    // Get the containing table row
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var newPrice = Number(row.find('.sell-price').val());
    var casecost = Number(row.find('.case-cost').val());
    ....
    // calculate results
    row.find('.gross-profit').val(grossprofit.toFixed(1))
});
```

As a side note, you should be checking the the values are valid (both `parseFloat` and `Number()` will return `NAN` if the value entered in the textbox is not valid), for example

```
if (isNaN(newPrice) || isNaN(casecost) {
    // its invalid and the calculation would fail
```

In addition, since `grossProfit` is a calculated value, it should not be generated as a textbox. Instead use a (say) `<span>` inside the `<td>` to display the calculated value (and the value should be recalculated on the server in the POST method to protect against malicious users altering the request)

Comment: this worked perfectly for my needs. 
Thanks a million @Stephen